# How to print the value of a map in ireport?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, datasource, ireport

I pass `Map<String, Set<Object>>` object as parameter to my ireport.
I want to print the  value `"Set<Object>"` on the custom created group if key in the map is equal to a field.

**Any Idea how to do it?**
thanks in advance

```
HashMap<String,Object> parameters = new HashMap<String,Object>();
parameters.put("PA_CHING",retreivePaChingMapping());

public Map<String, Set<Object>> retreivePaChingMapping() {
        Map<String, Set<Object>> paChing = GenericsUtil.makeMap();
        //adds the object to paChing here 
        return paChing;
    }
```

**In IReport:**

**parameter name:** PA_CHING

**parameter class type:** java.util.HashMap

**Default value expression:** i don't know what to put here.

**Expression of text field in ireport:**

```
$P{paChing}.containsKey( $F{id} ) ? getChing() : "null";

private void String getChing(){
    StringBuilder ching = new StringBuilder();
    $P{PA_CHInG}.get( $F{id} ).iterator().hasNext()?ching.append($P{PA_CHING}.get( $F{id} ).iterator().next):"";

    return ching;
}
```

Comment: Is GenericsUtil a class? If it is what does GenericsUtil.makeMap(); return?

Comment: It return HashMap<String, Set<Object>>

Answer (score 1):

Put a subreport inside the group detail then in the subreport's Datasource Expression, use

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(new java.util.ArrayList($P{PA_CHING}.get($F{field_where_you_match_the_key})))
```

Answer (score 0):

Set.toString() will do for you.

from Javadoc

> Returns a string representation of this collection. The string
>   representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the
>   order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets
>   ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (comma
>   and space). Elements are converted to strings as by
>   String.valueOf(Object).

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29)

Comment: I need to print the content of set<String> which consist of 3 or 4 string( a list of string)

Comment: The OP means "print" as in print inside jasperreport not convert into string.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a new:

```
            Map map=(Map) parameters.get("PA_CHING");
            Set<Object> set= (Set<Object>) map.get("your key name");
            YourClass class = (YourClass) set.iterator().next();
            System.out.println(class.yourMethodName());
     System.out.println(class.yourClassVariables);
```

Comment: Where should i declare it? In Default value expression or in Expression of text field in ireport?